# Interactive Book - Where to Start

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have been working for a few weeks now trying to create an interactive book. I have been reading blog after blog about Xcode. I have looked into storyboards and page apps. I can't find a  tutorial that just breaks down the process of creating a page based app and explains each part of the app. Like, for instance, how to lock orientation only one way for the iPad. How pulling HTML files works for the `UIWebView`. Is Javascript able to work on those pages? What can be put on a view and what can't?

I am not looking for people to answer these questions, if you can that would be great. My real question is, are there sites out there that people have used to get "up to snuff" to coding for the iPad or iOS 5? Is there a book out there that I can buy that stands out from the rest that is really helpful? Any direction will be helpful right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before looking for sites of questionable quality, did you try reading Apple's developer reference library?

Comment: @Costique Are you talking about the documentation? I took two hours reading up on that....and got nothing out of it.

Comment: i think the page based app on code 4.2 is for reading only. if you want to make an interactive book i think you schould use UIScrollView.

Comment: @SeongHo What is UIScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at iBooks Author and the new stuff you can easily do with an iBook?

Comment: Yeah, but they need educational components. I'm not sure ours will fit. Also, if we wanted to put apps inside this book, I am not sure that iBooks Author does that....

Comment: iBooks are not just for education.  You are right in that you can't embed iOS apps, you can embed HTML and Javascript to create custom widgets.

Comment: hmmmm well, I guess that is good. One problem is when you choose iAuthor, you can only have the book in Apple. Kiss your chances of getting into the Android Market goodbye.

Comment: Well, chances are if you are developing a book for the iPad (which is what the OP asked about), then you probably aren't worrying about the Android marketplace.

Comment: Actually I am later. But my main interest is getting on one device, then trying to get it on all devices. If its in HTML, in can be ported to a lot of devices right? BUT if I use iAuthor, I am stuck with just Apple. I am not going to limit myself. Sorry....